# Finding homeomorphisms, projective space

Tags: general-topology, geometry, differential-geometry

There are different approaches about this that's whuly I got lost, I would highly appreciate it if anyone adds a full, explained proofs for:

- $\Bbb RP^1$ is homeomorphic to $S^1$,
- $\Bbb CP^1$ is homeomorphic to $S^2$.

Definitions:

$RP^1=R^2\setminus{0}/{\sim}$ where $\sim$ is an equivalance proportion:
$x{\sim}\lambda x$ for all $x\in R^2\setminus {0}$ and $\lambda\in (R\setminus {0})$ respecting multiplication.

$S^1={x\in R^2 : ||x||=1}$ a circle

$S^2$ is the sphere

$CP^1=C^2\setminus {0})/{\sim}$ where $x{\sim}\lambda x$ iff $\lambda \ne 0\in C$

Comment: Both constructions are just adding a single point 'in infinity' to the line/plane, and removing a point from the circle/sphere yields a subspace homeomorphic to the line/plane, via *stereographic projection*.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Why don't you go the extra mile, and tell us what your definitions of those spaces are? For instance, is $S^1$ the set of points $(x, y)$ such that $x^2 + y^2 = 1$? Or is it the quotient of the closed unit interval under the equivalence relation that identifies $0$ and $1$? Or is it something else? Is $RP^1$ the set of all punctured lines through the origin in 2-space? If so, what's the topology on it, so that we can be sure we're writing a homeomorphism? (You can edit your question by clicking the light-gray "edit" just below it.)

Comment: I've edited your Mathjax to fix it. Pro tip: use more blanks than you think you need. Also: "\" is a special character; when you want a set-difference, use `\setminus`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First: your descriptions of the two projective planes are sloppy, and you should work on that.

Now let's get on to an answer:

Let's write the equivalence class containing $(a,b) \in \Bbb R^2$ as $[a, b]\in \Bbb RP^1$.

Then here is a homeomorphism from $\Bbb RP^1$ to $S^1$:
$$
[u, v] \mapsto (\frac{u^2 - v^2}{\sqrt{u^2 + v^2}}, \frac{2uv}{\sqrt{u^2 + v^2}}).
$$

How did I think of that? Well, each element of $\Bbb RP^1$ contains a point
$$(\cos a, \sin a)$$ of the upper semi-circle, i.e., for some $0 \le a < \pi$. And when we get to $a = \pi$ that's the same "element" as when $a = 0$. To send this to a full circle required doubling the angle, i.e., sending
$$
(\cos a, \sin a) \mapsto (\cos 2a , \sin 2a) = (\cos^2 a  - \sin^2 a, 2\sin a \cos a).
$$
That's the map I wrote down, but to get the "sine-and-cosine" form from an arbitrary (u,v) pair, I had to divide by the length of $(u, v)$ (namely $\sqrt{u^2 + v^2}$) to get a unit vector, which therefore HAD to be the sine-and-cosine of **something**, and I was done.

Why is this map a homeomorphism? Well, it's the restriction of a continuous map (*evidently* continuous, given the algebraic expression for it), or all of $\Bbb R^2$ except the origin, to $\Bbb R^2$; it's constant on equivalence classes, so you're done.

As for $\Bbb CP^1$ --- it might be easier to consider the map $[z, w] \mapsto z/w$ from $\Bbb CP^1 \setminus \{[1, 0]\}$ to the complex plane, and then wrap the complex plane over all of $S^2$ except the north pole via stereographic projection. Finally, send $[1, 0]$ to the north pole. In short: $\Bbb CP^1$ is homoeomorphic to the extended complex plane; the extended plane is homeomorphic to $S^2$, and you're done.

As an alternative, you can show that $\Bbb CP^1$ is a compact orientable surface, and then (with some effort) show that its Euler characteristic is $2$ via the Morse index theorem. Then, by the classification of compact surfaces, it must be homeomorphic to the sphere. But that's really killing a fly with a sledgehammer.

Comment: Thanks, isthere another explanation to why in part 1 is homeomorphism? Does using compactness or Hausdorff can be useful?  In part 2 i did not learn about stereographic projection so i didn't understand totally how it worked.

Comment: I think as i checked that in part 1 we have to divide by $u^2+v^2$ not the squrt of it.